# Actionscript make image in TextField.htmlText clickable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Actionscript's [TextField.htmlText property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) allows for `img` tag.  I''m wondering if it's somehow possible to make image clickable. More specifically, I would like to open a new window where I can display more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can surround it in a `<a>` tag.  like so:

```
var tt:String = '<a href="event:someThing"><img src="image.jpg"></a>';

var tf:TextField = new TextField;
tf.htmlText = tt;
tf.addEventListener("link",clickHandler);
addChild(tf);
```

then in callback:

```
public function clickHandler(e:TextEvent):void{
    trace(e.text);  // someThing
}
```

of course once you have it in callback you can do whatever you want.  open dialog, open webpage etc...